# what's the best way to recognize user device in Nuxt middleware

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, middleware, user-agent

Greeting,

I'm going to develop a web application using nuxtjs. For some reasons I need to recognize users' devices in the middleware. I know how to get user agent in req context, but it is hard to distinguish all devices manually. I also found [Nuxt/Device](https://github.com/nuxt-community/device-module) module but couldn't handle it in the middleware.
I try this code in my middleware file:

```
import device from '@nuxtjs/device'

export default (context) => {

  console.log(device)

}
```

buy I only get module details in my console. Please share your experience to help me.

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far? [This](https://github.com/nuxt-community/device-module#add-a-custom-flag) looks like something interesting and exactly what you want.

Comment: unfortunately I can't use that in 'middleware' file.

Comment: What did you tried so far? Mind sharing some actual code?

Comment: I update my question and add some code on it

Answer (score 0):

for using Nuxt/Device in middleware we had to run it in the context.app like:

```
export default (context) => {

  console.log(context.app.$device)

}
```